# ValidateInterceptor is not getting invoked when importing data from Impex

Tags: validation, e-commerce, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created one Interceptor to validate the data, when I am creating new object from HMC I can see the data is getting validated and throwing exception for wrong data but when I am trying to import wrong data from Imp-ex its not getting validated and Imported successfully. Legacy mode is turned off.

```
impex.legacy.mode=false

$canadasalesArea=salesArea(salesOrg(uid),distributionChannel(uid[default=00]),division(uid[default=00]))
$canadastoreConfig=CanadaStoreConfiguration
insert_update BooleanConfigType;configuration(name);salesDistrict(name,uid)[unique=true];soldTo(uid)[unique=true];name(code,itemtype(code))[unique=true,allownull=true];value;$canadasalesArea[unique=true,allownull=true]
;$canadastoreConfig;;11001859;enableEndecaBasedAPI:ConfigTypeName;true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the impex contains certain things ( e.g **[forceWrite = true]**, **[allownull=true]**) , even though legacy mode is set on false,
Legacy mode will be used for import and Interceptor will not intervene.

The whole logic which decides whether legacy mode will be used or not can be found in 
***DefaultImportProcessor***#***getHandlerForLine*** which calls this.***enableLegacyFlagWhenLineIsUsingJaloOnlyFeatures*** which calls ***ValueLine***#***isUsingJaloOnlyFeatures*** which can return true even though
**impex.legacy.mode=false**

I solved a simillar issue by excluding from impex **[forceWrite = true]** for one of my columns in 
Hybris 5.5.1.0

Also make sure that the legacy mode is not checked(settings) if the import is being performed from hac(hybris administration console)

Comment: I have  edited my question and added the Impex as well, I am not using 'forceWrite=true' or 'allownull=true'.

Comment: There are two "allownull=true" present in the impex

Comment: literally sorry haven't checked for allownull in the impex I have removed them and it worked perfectly for me, Thanks a lot:) where you got these type of info I searched in HYBRIS wiki but haven't got any thing.

Comment: Hardcore debugging :).I do not know whether this specific aspect is documented somewhere or not. Glad I could help.